# ActionBar Tabs weight/width

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I have an action bar with 3 tabs in it.
It looks like this:
       | All | Calls | Network |
 I want them to have the same width. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a tag to any view using setCustomView() method on the ActionBar.Tab.  This is how I did it.  The custom view is loaded from a layout that in my case was similar to the built-in layout used by ActionBar.Tag, you set the margins, sizes, and content to whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

They all align  in the row with same width

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"  >
<LinearLayout
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<HorizontalScrollView 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:fillViewport="true"
   android:scrollbars="none">
<TabWidget 
   android:id="@android:id/tabs"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
 </HorizontalScrollView>
 <FrameLayout
   android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
 </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

And then set tab host as

```
  TabHost tabHost;
TabHost.TabSpec spec;
tabHost=getTabHost()
Intent intent;
 intent=new Intent().setClass(this, BirthDayTab.class);
 spec=tabHost.newTabSpec("artists").setIndicator("BirthDay",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists)).setContent(intent);
 tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

Comment: No. You are talking about regular tabs. I am talking about **ActionBar Tabs**

Answer (score -1):

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/actionbarsherlock/4oT9KwhB0O8 
This is the exact solution that I have been looking for days